Unable to use puppeteer-core in electron-vite react app
I wanted to test how to use puppeteer-in-electron in my electron-vite app but due to issue with integrating puppeteer-core, I am unable to do so.
Steps to reproduce:

npm create electron-vite
Choose any project name, choose react and proceed.
cd into folder and npm install and then npm run dev to test a working app.
npm i puppeteer-core

My main.ts file looks like this:
import { app, BrowserWindow } from 'electron'
import path from 'node:path'
import pie from "puppeteer-in-electron";
import puppeteer from "puppeteer-core";

// The built directory structure
//
// ├─┬─┬ dist
// │ │ └── index.html
// │ │
// │ ├─┬ dist-electron
// │ │ ├── main.js
// │ │ └── preload.js
// │
process.env.DIST = path.join(__dirname, '../dist')
process.env.VITE_PUBLIC = app.isPackaged ? process.env.DIST : path.join(process.env.DIST, '../public')


let win: BrowserWindow | null
//  Use ['ENV_NAME'] avoid vite:define plugin - Vite@2.x
const VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL = process.env['VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL']

function createWindow() {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    icon: path.join(process.env.VITE_PUBLIC, 'electron-vite.svg'),
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
    },
  })

  // Test active push message to Renderer-process.
  win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
    win?.webContents.send('main-process-message', (new Date).toLocaleString())
  })

  if (VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
    win.loadURL(VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL)
  } else {
    // win.loadFile('dist/index.html')
    win.loadFile(path.join(process.env.DIST, 'index.html'))
  }
}

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
    win = null
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow()
  }
})

app.whenReady().then(async () => {
  await pie.initialize(app);
  const browser = await pie.connect(app, puppeteer);

  const window = new BrowserWindow();
  const url = "https://example.com/";
  await window.loadURL(url);

  const page = await pie.getPage(browser, window);
  console.log(page.url());
})

I am facing the below error when running npm run dev:
[vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "puppeteer-core" from "C:/Users/suraj/OneDrive/Desktop/test/electron-vite-project/electron/main.ts".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
`build.rollupOptions.external`
I tried adding build.rollupOptions.external as below in my config file but did not work.
This is how my vite.config.ts looks like
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import path from 'node:path'
import electron from 'vite-plugin-electron/simple'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
// import puppeteer from 'puppeteer-core'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      external: [
        'puppeteer-core',
      ],
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    react(),
    electron({
      main: {
        // Shortcut of `build.lib.entry`.
        entry: 'electron/main.ts',
      },
      preload: {
        // Shortcut of `build.rollupOptions.input`.
        // Preload scripts may contain Web assets, so use the `build.rollupOptions.input` instead `build.lib.entry`.
        input: path.join(__dirname, 'electron/preload.ts'),
      },
      // Ployfill the Electron and Node.js API for Renderer process.
      // If you want use Node.js in Renderer process, the `nodeIntegration` needs to be enabled in the Main process.
      // See  https://github.com/electron-vite/vite-plugin-electron-renderer
      renderer: {},
    }),
  ],
})

I tried the rollupOptions which seemed like the correct way to solve this issue as per vite's documentation. I am expecting vite to allow usage of puppeteer-core package. I think the config is correct way but not sure what I am missing.
Any suggestions would be welcome :)
